# Getting an updated array to update in a Vue3 template

Tags: javascript, templates, asynchronous, vuejs3

While this is not the exact code, it represents the issue. I have an object that has a method that returns an array. This array is then updated asynchronously. In the demo it is a timeout but in reality it would be an HTTP call:

```
function () {
 let a = ['apple'];

 setTimeout(() => {
   a.push['banana'];
 }, 3000);

 return a;
}
```

Then it is included in a Vue component via a computed property and displayed, e.g.

```
   <ul>
      <li v-for="(row, index) in testObjectArr" v-bind:key="index">
         {{row}}
      </li>
   </ul>
```

However this only displays the first entry (apple) and not the second (banana). If an event does cause the template to refresh then it does appear.
Using things like `watch` also doesn't work. The only way to get it working is to pass a handler in to the object that manually triggers a redraw which is oviously less than ideal.
Is there any way to get responsivity to actually work with the above situation?

Comment: You are not showing a computed property, but in general computed properties should NOT mutate the state.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make variables reactive, you should declare them as such by using `ref` or `reactive`. So your code should be:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const items = ref(['apple']);

setTimeout(() => {
  items.value.push('banana');
}, 1000);
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) of items" :key="index">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

[See it live](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-jcwh1d?file=src%2FApp.vue&terminal=dev)